when i send a post request with file, the local file was deleted with no reason
u.LogFilePath is absolute path of file,like "d://projectname//src//modelname//files//1.zip"
func upload(u *Param) {
    param := url.Values{}
    param.Add("partIndex", u.PartIndex)
    param.Add("partFileMd5", u.PartFileMD5)

    // get the byte buff of upload file
    writer, bff := createUploadFile(u.LogFilePath)
    url := os.Getenv(consts.HOST) + "/upload" + "?" + param.Encode()
    resp, err := http.Post(url, writer.FormDataContentType(), bff)
    // the file was deleted,why?
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("request to upload log error,%+v\r\n", err)
    }
    var response response.Response[struct{}]
    json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&response)
    if err = response.ValidateRespCode(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("upload log response error,%+v\r\n", err)
    }
}

// create bytes buff of upload file
func createUploadFile(path string) (*multipart.Writer, *bytes.Buffer) {
    var buff bytes.Buffer
    w := multipart.NewWriter(&buff)
    defer w.Close()
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    fw, _ := w.CreateFormFile("partLogFile", file.Name())
    if _, err := io.Copy(fw, file); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return w, &buff
}

Actually,this is a script for testing with Go,if the file was deleted,i have to copy files to the path again before run the script.
I don't know why the file was deleted after send a POST request.

I'm sure that the code you showed will not cause the file to be deleted. Could you please provide a complete example of reproducible?

Please use a better question title, check the stackoverflow help https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
